# How to determine the java2d uiscale factor?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, java-2d, highdpi

I know you can set the factor via -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2 but what if I want to let the System choose the Value, how do I get the value set? Where is it saved?

Comment: Put aside 'how' for the moment and focus on the *'why'.* ***Why*** do you think it's necessary to know this scaling factor?

Comment: Because I need to scale my JPanel with this factor. The paintComponent method doesnt get affected by this value, but it needs to.

Comment: Visualised here: https://ibb.co/54195Xv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can get the scale from the `Graphics` object that is passed to your `paint` method, you can also get it from [`GraphicsConfiguration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html) object using [`getDefaultTransform()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getDefaultTransform()) method.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to my assumption, JPanels get scaled by the uiScale Property. I reseted the Transform in a Superclass.. My bad